# Junit: Test if a file has been read properly

Tags: java, junit, junit4

please have a little bear with me, before voting me down ;). It's my first time with JUnit, and it's a simple question, knowing that:

Just want to test if the following file has been read as expected:

```
first
second
```

But why does my test fail:

```
@Test
public void testReadFileTwoRows() {
    File f = new File(FILE_WITH_TWO_ROWS);
    String fileCont = "";       
    String expCont  = "first\nsecond";

    try {           
        fileCont = ImportUtil.readFile(f);
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        fail("File couldn't be read");
    }
    assertEquals("File was not properly read", fileCont, expCont);      
}
```

I think it has somethings to do with "\n" but I don't see another way to write that check.

Thanks a lot

Comment: hard to tell without knowing the code of your (I suppose it is your code...) `ImportUtil.readFile(f)` routine...

Comment: What do you have in fileCont?

Comment: print and see the contents of `fileCont`. Tell us, what it contains.

Comment: Perhaps readFile converts line terminators to \r\n pairs. Perhaps the files ARE different. Perhaps the implementation of readFile is wrong...

Comment: Javier you are right: It was converted to \r\n, as you said... thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: but what is _actually_ contained in `fileCont`?? The line terminator is kinda important in this issue...

Comment: fileCont is as expected: (1) first (2) second